# How can I clone a socket in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, sockets

I'm writing a file transfer client/server program in Ruby.  My client can send a get, send, or list command to the server.  After the TCPServer.accept call I have a socket for the client, which I am using for the receiving  of commands.

When a command comes in I want to open another socket and thread for the transfer of data, this way I can keep the original socket and thread open to continue accepting commands, and kill the data socket and thread when the data transfer is complete.

If I have a TCPSocket sock can I use sock.clone()?

I have done this sort of implementation before in other languages but am unsure of how to do it in Ruby.

Comment: Did you look [this?](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/socket/rdoc/TCPServer.html)

Comment: dddd1919 yes I did, my server started out as the 2nd TCPServer example on that page.  I want to use that socket created on the accept call as the command socket and open another socket to the same client every time they request data.

Comment: When a socket arrived, a new `thread` begin to deal with it apart of main process, like 'another socket', don't you?

Comment: @dddd1919 Yes.  I want to keep that socket and thread open for the duration of the clients connection to the server.  When the server receives a command from the client I want to open another socket and thread specifically for the data transfer.  Should I just be copying the sockaddr info of the clients first socket and bind it to a new socket/port#?

Comment: I think that 2nd sample has solve your problem. With that code, TCPclient will keep alive and when socket arrive, it make a new thread to deal with socket until complete, meanwhile client begin to wait next socket arrive, they are synchronous.

Comment: @dddd1919 The 2nd sample is what I am using at the moment.  That client socket is what I want to use as my command channel, and when that socket receives a command I want to open an additional socket and thread.

Comment: When `Thread.start(server.accept)` there is already a new thread and a socket replica.

Comment: @dddd1919 I know that, I want another in addition to the one created on server.accept